# Can we migrate plugin suggestion requests instead of closing?

Tags: discussion

My understanding on the migration policy from site-to-site is the site that a Q&A would be migrated to must be graduated and the question can not be older then a few months.

That said, when we get plugin requests can we just migrate them to [Software Recommendation SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)? It would appear based on their [WordPress tag](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) that they allow them instead of just closing them.

I think migrating instead of closing would be more helpful, as it seems once questions have been downvoted and closed, the user doesn't return (from possible intimidation) - even though that is not the intent.

When trying to leave a comment informing the user these types of questions aren't in scope, it seems some users do not understand the separation - and that leads to frustration.

Some sample plugin questions:

- [Responsive Slider Plugin supporting WP Native Galleries, Srcset, Lazy Load?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/236110/responsive-slider-plugin-supporting-wp-native-galleries-srcset-lazy-load)
- [custom intro-box plugin similar to author box style with per post customizable title, desc, image & social links](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/235901/custom-intro-box-plugin-similar-to-author-box-style-with-per-post-customizable-t)
- [Suggestion for plugins for content scheduling + pay per publishing](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/236116/suggestion-for-plugins-for-content-scheduling-pay-per-publishing)

If we do choose this approach, would we also modify the close reason?

Comment: I have put your question into their chat, so we can get their view. They would have the additional after all.

Comment: If the mods over on SRSE are onboard, I'm onboard! I'm not sure what the process would be to get them on the migration list though. I believe they already have a site-ad in our sidebar so it would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

We can send such questions to Software Recommendations (SR), but we should be very careful, and we should not add SR to the existing list of migration sites in that close reason.

SR is expecting a certain quality from these questions, outlined here:

[What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

What we can do: We ask the OP to edit the question while it is still on our site until it fits these requirements. **Then** we can migrate it.

We are not the first site with that problem. See [Where to ask for app recommendations?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2060/where-to-ask-for-app-recommendations) for a similar discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking which is not already possible?

There is a "close > Off-topic > This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" path.

Though I must note that it is notoriously hard to make good migrations without being closely acquainted with the *target* stack. For example it took us a while to get finer points of our scope through to Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: I was curious if I should either flag them for migration or should I keep flagging them to be closed.

Comment: As per answer I wouldn't know to say either way without spending time on Software Recs site and figuring out which Qs precisely would do good there. That's the main challenge with migrations.